# Update custom type using both FirebaseAuth and custom collection

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Note: I'm fairly new to FireBase so bear with me please.

I'm creating an app that involves having a user. Now this user has many different properties like birthday: name, email, Date(), location, etc. which cannot be stored if I were to use Firebase authentication (as far as I know) since that only allows me to store basic things like email, id, etc. So I have a collection that stores my users where each user is as follows:
[image]

And here is a sc from the database :

[image]

Now I want to be able to keep track of the current user somehow and from the codecademy.com course they said to have an AuthService file as follows:

```swift
//
//  AuthService.swift
//  Socialcademy
//
//  Created by John Royal on 1/9/22.
//

import FirebaseAuth

@MainActor
class AuthService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
    
    private let auth = Auth.auth()
    private var listener: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    init() {
        listener = auth.addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] _, user in
            self?.user = user.map { User(from: $0) }
        }
    }
    
    func createAccount(name: String, email: String, password: String) async throws {
        let result = try await auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
        try await result.user.updateProfile(\.displayName, to: name)
        user?.name = name
    }
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) async throws {
        try await auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
    }
    
    func signOut() throws {
        try auth.signOut()
    }
    
    func updateProfileImage(to imageFileURL: URL?) async throws {
        guard let user = auth.currentUser else {
            preconditionFailure("Cannot update profile for nil user")
        }
        guard let imageFileURL = imageFileURL else {
            try await user.updateProfile(\.photoURL, to: nil)
            if let photoURL = user.photoURL {
                try await StorageFile.atURL(photoURL).delete()
            }
            return
        }
        async let newPhotoURL = StorageFile
            .with(namespace: "users", identifier: user.uid)
            .putFile(from: imageFileURL)
            .getDownloadURL()
        try await user.updateProfile(\.photoURL, to: newPhotoURL)
    }
}

private extension User {
    init(from firebaseUser: FirebaseAuth.User) {
        self.id = firebaseUser.uid
        self.name = firebaseUser.displayName ?? ""
        self.imageURL = firebaseUser.photoURL
    }
}

private extension FirebaseAuth.User {
    func updateProfile<T>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<UserProfileChangeRequest, T>, to newValue: T) async throws {
        var profileChangeRequest = createProfileChangeRequest()
        profileChangeRequest[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
        try await profileChangeRequest.commitChanges()
    }
}
```

Where their user is defined as:

```swift
//
//  User.swift
//  Socialcademy
//
//  Created by John Royal on 1/9/22.
//

import Foundation

struct User: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var imageURL: URL?
}

extension User {
    static let testUser = User(
        id: "",
        name: "Jamie Harris",
        imageURL: URL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/lw9LrnpUmWw/480x480")
    )
}
```

Now what I want to do is to keep track of my current user who has more fields than those that I can access using FirebaseAuth.User (hence I created my collection). From what I understand the part of code that takes care of this auto updating of the user (eg. when imageURL is changed) is the init() method of the AuthService:

```swift
   init() {
        listener = auth.addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] _, user in
            self?.user = user.map { User(from: $0) }
        }
    }
```

So what I want to do is to create this listener however instead of setting self?.user to a FirebaseAuth.User, I want to use the extra fields I have in the collection "users_v5" to set this user everytime. Now I tried to create a new init() function for User like so:

```swift
    init(from firebaseUser: FirebaseAuth.User) async throws {
        let usersReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users_v5")
        let user: User = try await usersReference.whereField("id", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid).getDocuments(as: User.self)[0]
        self.id = user.id
        self.name = user.name
        self.email = user.email
        self.imageURL = user.imageURL
        self.birthday = user.birthday
        self.phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber
        self.usersPosts = user.usersPosts
        self.eventsAttending = user.eventsAttending
    }
```

However when I try to modify what the listener is initialized to I keep on getting errors that involve the async nature of the init I created. But there is no other way to access these fields from the users collection without an async call.
So my question is how can I initialize this listener such that it accesses fields from the users collection (using the id FirebaseAuth.User object thats in the closure).

Thank you so much in advance I appreciate any help!